# sdwebimage header can not be found

Tags: swift, xcode

I am receiving the following error: `SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h` file not found.

I have tried steps from the same question asked and no luck. I have tried renaming the search paths of the headers and frameworks, etc. I have also tried adding the file to the xcode project, running clean build, changing the `<>` to `""` next to the import statement. After one week of troubleshooting, unsure of what else I can try.

Is there other things I could try?

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: I re installed the podfile and all was well

Comment: In swift you should use import SDWebImage. As I kwnow, you shouldn't add this library to bridging header.